# How to Codesign and Sandbox Helper Application in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, submission

This is the problem: 
I have a MainApp that contains an HelperApp. The Helper app is used for the login items so i need to differentiate MainApp and HelperApp bundle IDs.
I copied the HelperApp into MainApp thanks to the BuildPhase Copy.
If I Codesign and Sandbox the HelperApp the upload phase stops... with error related to the provisioning profile. 
If I don't code sign/sandbox the HelperApp the upload works but after 2 minutes I receive an invalid binary" that warns me about the "App sandbox not enabled" on the helper app.

Do you know which is the correct practice to Sandbox and app with Helper app in it? 
I can't find NOTHING in the documentation!

Comment: why don't you start a bounty?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same scenario: a MainApp that contains a HelperApp, which is used to launch the MainApp at login.

The "invalid binary  - app sandbox not enabled" problem got resolved by making sure that the Code Signing Identity for **both** apps in XCode is set to "**3rd Party Mac Developer Application**".

Then, after submitting for review, I got the "Waiting for Review" notification and no more "invalid binary" errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting your helper app, then adding it again this way: in Xcode go to file, add new files to "Your project", and import your helper app.  Then, make sure they both have valid provisioning profiles for distribution.