# How to create an Helper app in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Codesign and Sandbox Helper Application in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231712/how-to-codesign-and-sandbox-helper-application-in-xcode-4)

In these days i'm having some problems with helper for OSX application. I need to create an Helper App with bundle id different from the "father" app which will contains this Helper.

I'm pretty sure that all my problems are related to the creation of the Helper and its inclusion in the Main App.

I do these steps:

1. I create 2 projects, one for the MainApp and one for the Helper
2. I Build the HelperApp (with its code sign and its entitlements)
3. I add the Helper.app file to the MainApp through "copy files" in "Bundle Phases"
4. I Build the MainApp (with its code sign and its entitlements)

The final application works as expected, but the entitlements of the HelperApp creates error during the validation of the MainApp archive and so i can't submit the app.

What do you think about those steps? are them correct? and what about the entitlements and sandbox of the Helper App?

EDIT---
I codosign my Apps with XCode, but I realize that many developer use the command `code sign` from the terminal. Could it be part of the issues?

Comment: possible repost of [How to Codesign and Sandbox Helper Application in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231712/how-to-codesign-and-sandbox-helper-application-in-xcode-4)

Comment: If you want to enhance your earlier question on the same topic, please feel free to edit this new information into it. Just please don't ask the same question multiple times.